# Permissions for Windows Server 2008 R2 NFS Share Files

Tags: windows-server-2008-r2, permissions, nfs, hp-ux

I have configured and am using a NFS share on a Windows 2008 server. I am copying files from a Unix server using anonymous access. What I cannot figure out is how to get the file permissions working on the Windows side. I cannot rename or copy the files without editing the permissions for each file individually. I have set the permissions on the containing folder, but no new files copied inside the folder inherit the folder's permissions.

How do I get the permissions to be the same for all new files that are added to that folder?

Comment: Did you ever find a solution to this? I'm having the same issue!!

Answer (score 1):

Checkout: http://blogs.technet.com/b/sfu/archive/2009/08/28/how-nfs-access-works-over-ntfs-permissions.aspx

The registry key mentioned in the post fixed the inheritance problem for us.

Comment: The URL for the technet article changed.  https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/blogs/technet/sfu/how-nfs-access-works-over-ntfs-permissions

Answer (score 0):

There are a few things that could be in play here, but it's almost always one of the two below causes

1. It's a network share, so make sure the "sharing" permissions settings aren't in conflict with your NTFS permissions.  (Best practice is to allow `Everyone` full access in the share permissions and control access with the NTFS permissions).
2. Ensure the permissions are set to propagate down from the root (or parent folders, as appropriate).  From the folder context menu, `Properties` <kbd>-></kbd> `Security` tab <kbd>-></kbd> `Advanced` button <kbd>-></kbd> `Permissions` tab <kbd>-></kbd> `Change Permissions` button <kbd>-></kbd> `Edit...` button.  As in the screenshot below, if you want the permissions to apply to child objects, you need to have it applied to the appropriate subset (which is usually `This folder, subfolder and files`), rather than `This folder only`.

[image: Permissions dialogue]

And of course, depending on your use-case and desires, you may wish to use the option to replace the permissions on all child objects with the ones you're defining, but obviously, be careful, and aware that it can take a while for a lot of files.

Comment: I just checked this and the settings are already done this way. The permissions are supposed to be propagating down but are not. When the files are copied over from unix they are not getting an owner since we are doing anonymous access. I think that is the biggest stumbling block here, but I dont know how to overcome it.

Comment: @eptiliom  Change the owner.  You can do so at the root/parent folder and apply the new owner to all subcontainers and objects as well.

Comment: That works for the existing files, but not new ones.